# Idiomatic way of testing a Diamond smart contract

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, solidity

I've been writing and testing solidity code for quite a while, and I've been finding myself using the [`smock2`](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock) library quite extensively. In a nutshell, making sure that during a `ContractA` test, testing that `ContractA` calls `ContractB` rather than testing that the actual side effects of the `ContractB` call. It allows for great separation of concerns and reduces code duplication.

However, when working with EIP-2535 (aka Diamond pattern), I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to avoid testing `FacetB` from `FacetA`, when for example a method of `FacetA` calls `FacetB(address(this)).doSomething()`.

Is there an accepted way to mock facets? Or otherwise, is there an idiomatic way of testing facets separately, even if they rely on one another? Ideally without having to duplicate `FacetB` into a solidity mock just used for testing...

I usually use [`hardhat`](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat) (Along with `ethers`) and [`hardhat-deploy`](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy) and unfortunately there's very little documentation for the later.
Extra points would go for anything utilizing `hardhat-deploy`'s fixtures along with `smock`.